# clickhouse: create materialized view on startup (docker)

Tags: docker, clickhouse

I'm trying to set up a local development docker with a materialized view on startup. So having this Dockerfile:

```yaml
FROM yandex/clickhouse-server:20.6.4.44
COPY default /var/lib/clickhouse/metadata/default
```

And in `default` we have these 2 definitions:

`a_table.sql`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE default.a_table (
    `startTimestamp` DateTime,
    `fieldNumber` UInt32,
    `clientCountry` UInt16,
    `packets` UInt64,
    `bytes` UInt64
)
ENGINE = SummingMergeTree()
PARTITION BY toYYYYMM(startTimestamp)
ORDER BY (startTimestamp, clientCountry)
SETTINGS index_granularity = 8192
```

And the view, `v_by_country_15m.sql`::

```sql
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW v_by_country_15m 
ENGINE = SummingMergeTree()
PARTITION BY toYYYYMM(startTimestamp)
PRIMARY KEY (startTimestamp, clientCountry)
ORDER BY (startTimestamp, clientCountry)
AS (
       SELECT startTimestamp,
              clientCountry,
              sum(bytes) as bytes
       FROM a_table
       GROUP BY startTimestamp, clientCountry
)
```

If I only include the `a_table.sql` file in the `default` folder, the container starts up normally but if I include the `v_by_country_15m.sql` file in the `default` folder, it fails to startup. If I start with only the table, and then `exec` and `clickhouse-client` and just create the materialized view, it works, so I don't think the issue is the materialized view itself.

Can we have materialized views on startup?

Comment: but metadata folder store attach scripts not create

Comment: Hi @DennyCrane But it seems to make no difference when it's a table (the table is created). What's the difference in practice?

Comment: The difference is huge, I cannot explain it in the comment. You should use attach.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Changed everything to `ATTACH` but now have another issue.. Can you help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67348100/clickhouse-attach-materialized-view-error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It needs to copy sql-scripts to [/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/](https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/blob/master/docker/server/README.md#volumes)-folder:

```yaml
FROM yandex/clickhouse-server:20.6.4.44
COPY default/* /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

Check it:

```sh
docker build -t test_ch:latest  .
docker run test_ch

docker exec -it {container-id} bash
> clickhouse client
  > USE default
  > SHOW TABLES
  > ┌─name────────────────────┐
  > │ .inner.v_by_country_15m │
  > │ a_table                 │
  > │ v_by_country_15m        │
  > └─────────────────────────┘
```