# clickhouse attach materialized view error

Tags: docker, clickhouse

Given this dockerfile

```
FROM yandex/clickhouse-server:20.6.4.44
COPY default /var/lib/clickhouse/metadata/default
```

And having these sql files in the `default` directory:

```
ATTACH TABLE IF NOT EXISTS default.a_table (
    `startTimestamp` DateTime,
    `fieldNumber` UInt32,
    `clientCountry` UInt16,
    `packets` UInt64,
    `bytes` UInt64
)
ENGINE = MergeTree()
PARTITION BY toYYYYMM(startTimestamp)
ORDER BY (startTimestamp, clientCountry)
SETTINGS index_granularity = 8192
```

```
ATTACH TABLE IF NOT EXISTS default.net_by_country_15m (
    `startTimestamp` DateTime,
    `clientCountry` UInt16,
    `bytes` UInt64
)
ENGINE = SummingMergeTree()
PARTITION BY toYYYYMM(startTimestamp)
ORDER BY (startTimestamp, clientCountry)
SETTINGS index_granularity = 8192;
```

And this view:

```
ATTACH MATERIALIZED VIEW v_by_country_15m TO default.net_by_country_15m
AS (
       SELECT startTimestamp,
              clientCountry,
              sum(bytes) as bytes
       FROM default.a_table
       GROUP BY startTimestamp, clientCountry
)
```

the container doesn't start and running the statement manually I get

```
Received from localhost:9000. DB::Exception: Table `v_by_country_15m` doesn't exist.
```

(this is a follow up to [clickhouse: create materialized view on startup (docker)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67339196/clickhouse-create-materialized-view-on-startup-docker) but instead of using the `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` directory, I want to keep using the `metadata` directory since this is a project I inherited and don't wanna change too much until I understand clickhouse better).

(updated table definitions)

Comment: `FROM another_table` What is another_table? In which database this table?

Comment: It's in the same db. Just updated the table definitions to more closely resemble what I'm trying to do. I create the `inner` table of the view myself (net_by_country_15m) and then try to attach the view but it isnt working.

Comment: Using `CREATE` works though.

Answer (score 0):

it should be `TO default.a_table`

```
ATTACH MATERIALIZED VIEW v_by_country_15m  to default.a_table
AS (
       SELECT startTimestamp,
              clientCountry,
              sum(bytes) as bytes
       FROM another_table
       GROUP BY startTimestamp, clientCountry
)
```

Comment: That was actually a copy-paste error. I did have the `TO` there. Anyway, run it again and the error is the same: `DB::Exception: Table v_by_country_15m doesn't exist.`.  Thanks for your help